# How to make custom total price reactive in navigation

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, javascript

I created navigation for my custom template and added total price inside the `<li></li>` elements and it show the price if I add product to the cart, but if I add another product to cart price not change automatically. If I want the price updated, I need to refresh the whole page.

Can someone help me to make this price updating automatically if I add products to cart? I'm very bad about ajax etc... but I want this to working like it should work.

```
<ul class="nav-link-right">
    <li class="nav-link-price">
          
          <?php if ( class_exists( 'Woocommerce' ) ) : ?>

          <?php 

          // Get order total 
          $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

          ?>

          <span id="order-total-price"><?php echo $cart_total; ?></span>


    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using woocommerce `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` filter you can do that.

Going by the `id` attribute that you currently have for the span that displays the cart total, you can use the following code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'bt_update_cart_total');
function bt_update_cart_total ($fragments) {
    $fragments['#order-total-price'] = '<span id="order-total-price">' . WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() . '</span>';

    return $fragments;
}
```

Add this code to your functions.php file and thats it.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.